# Hide element on ONLY home page of WordPress using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to hide the element .gdlr-page-title-wrapper on the home page of https://colerainefc.com - a WordPress site.

I have tried: .home #gdlr-page-title-wrapper   { display: none; }

Any idea what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a class, not ID, so dont use **#** but **.**

```
.home .gdlr-page-title-wrapper { display: none; }
```